# Sign an application with certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do i sign my application with a distribution certificate? I did make a distribution certificate on the provisioning portal but now when i'm trying to upload the zipped app file withth application loader it says it's not signed with the certificate.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the certificate from the provisioning portal, and double
   click it. This will "install" it on your Mac.
2. Edit your project schema and select "Release" as it's build
       configuration.
3. Under project settings select the "Build Settings" tab. Edit the
       "Code Signing Identity" for "release" to ensure that it's referencing
       the correct certificate.

If pictures help with that process, [this link](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html) looks like it might be helpful.